# Getting a value of a cell in a selected row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I need to do is compare a value from a textbox to every cell in a certain column of a gridview, to determine if they are the same. I have looked around extensively for a way to get the value of a cell in a gridview, but I haven't had anything work for me.

Here is the code I am currently trying to work off of (not sure if this is at all the right direction, or the best way to go about this):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = 0;
    while (number < GridView1.Rows.Count)
    {
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = number;

    }
number++;
}
```

Now I want to compare the value in a textbox to, for example, every cell in "Column 3" of my gridview.

Comment: Looks like an endless loop to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm crazy, but this seems to do the trick.  One problem is if you are changing the row collection you won't be able to because it is in a foreach loop.

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[3].Text == tbNumberSource.Text)
            { 
                // Match Found
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured it would be something simple looking like this, but I hadn't been able to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    foreach(var row in GridfView1.Rows)
    {
       if(row.Index!=selectedRowIndex)
       {
         if(row.Cells["IndexOfColumn"].Text==TextBox.Text))
         {
             // Do what you want here
         }
       }
    }
}
```